# ndk-r7 can not identify the va_list type

Tags: android

I have set up the ndk-r7 compiling environment in Eclipse and compile the C code for .so library file. Then the va_lsit type of C code can not be identified and be compiled.

It is no problem when I compile sample code of ndk. But it did not use va_list type in sample. It has stdarg.h. And it has the va_list definition in some stdarg.h of ndk catalogue.

The error like this:

```
jni/CommAbstractLayer.c: In function 'SetCommunicationLineVoltage':
jni/CommAbstractLayer.c:1414: error: invalid initializer（this line points the following line: va_list   args = NULL;）
```

The code like this:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
......
W_INT2 SetCommunicationLineVoltage(BYTE ucChangeTimes, ...)
{
va_list args = NULL;
......
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe with [NDK version 8](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/Q8ajOD37LR0) the error will go away, otherwise look for the solution of a similar problem: [Android NDK: Function va_start / va_end could not be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720411/android-ndk-function-va-start-va-end-could-not-be-resolved).

Answer (score 0):

`va_list` isn't guaranteed to be a pointer; that code isn't valid C.

That line can be modified to simply read

```
va_list args;
```

provided that the code does initialize it with `va_start` and doesn't assume that it's comparable to `NULL`.